# Diffie-Hellman key exchange for $n + 1$ parties

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman

Suppose that there are $n+1$ parties - $B,A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ that want to share a secret key

The protocol of exchanging is roughly the same as Diffe-Hellman

Chose a group $G$ with an order of $p$ - a prime number and a generator element $g$

- Each $A_i$ generates a random number $a_i \in \{1,...,p\}$ and send $B$ the value $X_i \leftarrow g^{a_i} $
- B generates a random number $b \in \{1,...,p\}$ and send each $A_i$ the value $Y_i \leftarrow X_i^b$

The shared key of the group is $g^b$

It is obvious that $B$ can calculate this key.

How can each $A_i$ calculate the shared key ?

I tried finding the inverse $a_i^{-1}$ of $a_i$ in mod $p$ and then taking both sides of $Y_i=g^{a_ib}$ to the power of $a_i^{-1}$ but when I plug in real numbers, it does not seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in the (revised) question is (mostly†) OK. That is, $A_i$ calculates the shared key as $Y_i^{a_i^{-1}\bmod p}$, where the exponentiation is in the group $G$ of order $p$. And (assuming no alteration of messages) every party including $B$ gets the same shared key, because
$$\begin{align}
Y_i^{a_i^{-1}\bmod p}&={X_i}^{b\,(a_i^{-1}\bmod p)}\\
&=g^{a_i\,(b\,(a_i^{-1}\bmod p))}\\
&=g^{b\,(a_i\,(a_i^{-1}\bmod p))}\\
&=g^{b\,(k\,p+1)}&&\text{for some }k\in\mathbb Z\\
&=g^{p\,k\,b+b}\\
&=(g^p)^{k\,b}\,g^b\\
&=1^{k\,b}\,g^b&&\text{because the order of }g\text{ is }p\\
&=g^b
\end{align}
$$

Given that the [initial question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/107112/1) used two primes, it's possible that a confusion is made between a prime modulus $n$ used to compute in the group $G$, and the prime order $p$ (formerly $q$) of group $G$ and it's generator $g$. That would explain why numerical experiments fail.

Among many others, our options include:

1. Making $G$ an unspecified abstract group of order $p$, and not making numerical experiments.
2. Making $G$ the subgroup of quadratic residues of [$\mathbb Z_n^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) for $n$ a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime), which has prime order $p$ the matching [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) with $p=(n-1)/2$. A toy (unsafe) example is $n=83$, $p=41$. An actual example of such group is the [2048-bit MODP group of RFC 3526](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3526#section-3).
3. Making $G$ a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group), that is a subgroup $G$ of prime order $p$ of $\mathbb Z_n^*$. Then $p$ must be a prime divisor of $n-1$. This extends the above, allowing smaller $p$ thus faster operation. An actual example of such group is the [2048-bit MODP group with 256-bit prime order subgroup of RFC 5114](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5114.html#section-2.3).
4. Using an elliptic curve of prime order $n$ on the prime field $\mathbb F_n$. An actual example would be [secp256r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.2) (except using the $p$ there as our $n$ and the $n$ there as our $p$), with the group operation described [in sec1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1).

---

† <sup>It fails when one of the $a_i$ is $p$, but that has vanishing probability $1-(1-1/p)^n$.</sup>

Comment: Its my bad I mistyped p and q

Comment: @Kain: I have updated the answer to match the modified question and detail the computation in a proof of correctness. Make sure to refresh the page.